# AVFoundation crop captured still image according to the preview aspect ratio

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, avfoundation

My question is mostly similar to this one:

[Cropping image captured by AVCaptureSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780580/cropping-image-captured-by-avcapturesession)

I have an application which uses AVFoundation for capturing still images. My AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer has AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill video gravity thus making preview picture which is shown to the user to be cropped from the top and from the bottom parts.

When user is pressing "Capture" button, the image actually captured is differs from the preview picture shown to user. My question is how to crop captured image accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The captured image differs from the preview image because you are resizing for aspect fill, right? So, instead why not either change the property to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect` or resize the dimensions of your preview layer to match the proportions of your capture image?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used `UIImage+Resize` category provided in [here](https://github.com/jeremybrooks/TestOverlay/blob/master/TestOverlay/UIImage-categories) with some new methods I wrote to do the job. I reformatted some code to look better and not tested, but it should work. :))

```
- (UIImage*)cropAndResizeAspectFillWithSize:(CGSize)targetSize
                       interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {

    UIImage *outputImage = nil;
    UIImage *imageForProcessing = self;

    // crop center square (AspectFill)
    if (self.size.width != self.size.height) {
        CGFloat shorterLength = 0;
        CGPoint origin = CGPointZero;
        if (self.size.width > self.size.height) {
            origin.x = (self.size.width - self.size.height)/2;
            shorterLength = self.size.height;
        }
        else {
            origin.y = (self.size.height - self.size.width)/2;
            shorterLength = self.size.width;
        }
        imageForProcessing = [imageForProcessing normalizedImage];
        imageForProcessing = [imageForProcessing croppedImage:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, shorterLength, shorterLength)];
    }
    outputImage = [imageForProcessing resizedImage:targetSize interpolationQuality:quality];
    return outputImage;
}

// fix image orientation, which may wrongly rotate the output.
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage {
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    [self drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, self.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Comment: How would this method help to crop the image?

Comment: It looks that it resizes a given image, but not crop it

Comment: You're right. I realized that too but forgot to fix my answer. Will do it shortly ;)

Comment: there you go, please have a look

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Would it work if I need to consider the x and y of the image as well? As in my case, I located the VideoPreviewLayer of the AVCamera in x=3, y=67 location of the screen and the size is 310X310