# How to capture image of particular co-ordinates in iphone?

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay

I am new to iphone development. I am creating one camera app, in that i need to capture only some co-ordinates of the image for example (I have overlay image on camera. that image is dollar. In the middle of the dollar bill there is a rectangle. inside this rectangle i can set my own image and capture).That is working fine. But when i save i need to save only image inside the rectangle co-ordinates. How to capture that. Please can anyone help me. Here is my code sample.

```
OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

// Create a new image picker instance:
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

// Set the image picker source:
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Hide the controls:
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

// Make camera view full screen:
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);

// Insert the overlay:
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

// Show the picker:
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  
[picker release];
```

Comment: You may process the captured image before saving. You may crop the captured image between the desired coordinates and save it.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780580/cropping-image-captured-by-avcapturesession

Comment: @Hadley how to set the iphone camera screen size to my custom size.

Comment: no need to change the screen size, just use the delegate method which will give you the image captured and being stored in Photos and call this function to the place before saving and after capturing.

Comment: -(void)recorder:(AVCamRecorder *)recorder recordingDidFinishToOutputFileURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL error:(NSError *)error ,

probably this is the best suitable for you.

Comment: for taking picture , this delegate method is used, use this - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer  fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection , hope you understood